# Youtube Watch Me Android application closing unexpectedly

Tags: android, ffmpeg, youtube-api, apk, live-streaming

I create android application from https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme.

When I try to create the event using the "CREATE LIVE EVENT" button.It throws some following error. I think it's happening due to the camera permission issue.

ERROR:

```
09-17 11:43:53.582  32383-32383/com.google.android.apps.watchme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.apps.watchme, PID: 32383
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.checkSelfPermission
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.startStreaming(StreamerActivity.java:174)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.access$200(StreamerActivity.java:46)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity$1.onServiceConnected(StreamerActivity.java:63)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1110)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1127)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any one please suggest . How can I solve this issue.

Thanks In Advance

Code Update:

Manifest file XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.apps.watchme">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- For authorization. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- For recording audio and video without going to lock. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission."/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"></uses-feature>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true"></uses-feature>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.watchme.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>

        <service android:name="com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
</manifest>
```

Stream Activity File

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.google.android.apps.watchme;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.google.android.apps.watchme.util.Utils;
import com.google.android.apps.watchme.util.YouTubeApi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Ibrahim Ulukaya <ulukaya@google.com>
 *         <p/>
 *         StreamerActivity class which previews the camera and streams via StreamerService.
 */
public class StreamerActivity extends Activity {
    // CONSTANTS
    // TODO: Stop hardcoding this and read values from the camera's supported sizes.
    public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 640;
    public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_MICROPHONE = 0;

    // Member variables
    private StreamerService streamerService;
    private ServiceConnection streamerConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onServiceConnected");

            streamerService = ((StreamerService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

            restoreStateFromService();
            startStreaming();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onServiceDisconnected");

            // This should never happen, because our service runs in the same process.
            streamerService = null;
        }
    };
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    private Preview preview;
    private String rtmpUrl;
    private String broadcastId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        broadcastId = getIntent().getStringExtra(YouTubeApi.BROADCAST_ID_KEY);
        //Log.v(MainActivity.APP_NAME, broadcastId);

        rtmpUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(YouTubeApi.RTMP_URL_KEY);

        if (rtmpUrl == null) {
            Log.w(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "No RTMP URL was passed in; bailing.");
            finish();
        }
        Log.i(MainActivity.APP_NAME, String.format("Got RTMP URL '%s' from calling activity.", rtmpUrl));

        setContentView(R.layout.streamer);
        preview = (Preview) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewPreview);

        if (!bindService(new Intent(this, StreamerService.class), streamerConnection,
                BIND_AUTO_CREATE | BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND)) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "Failed to bind StreamerService!");
        }

        final ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleBroadcasting);
        toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
                    streamerService.startStreaming(rtmpUrl);
                } else {
                    streamerService.stopStreaming();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onResume");

        super.onResume();

        if (streamerService != null) {
            restoreStateFromService();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onPause");

        super.onPause();

        if (preview != null) {
            preview.setCamera(null);
        }

        if (streamerService != null) {
            streamerService.releaseCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "onDestroy");

        super.onDestroy();

        if (streamerConnection != null) {
            unbindService(streamerConnection);
        }

        stopStreaming();

        if (streamerService != null) {
            streamerService.releaseCamera();
        }
    }

    private void restoreStateFromService() {
        preview.setCamera(Utils.getCamera(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT));
    }

    private void startStreaming() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "startStreaming");

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, this.getClass().getName());
        wakeLock.acquire();

        if (!streamerService.isStreaming()) {

            String cameraPermission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
            String microphonePermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
            int hasCamPermission = checkSelfPermission(cameraPermission);
            int hasMicPermission = checkSelfPermission(microphonePermission);
            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (hasCamPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(cameraPermission);
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    // Provide rationale in Snackbar to request permission
                    Snackbar.make(preview, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                } else {
                    // Explain in Snackbar to turn on permission in settings
                    Snackbar.make(preview, R.string.permission_camera_explain,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                }
            }
            if (hasMicPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissions.add(microphonePermission);
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                    // Provide rationale in Snackbar to request permission
                    Snackbar.make(preview, R.string.permission_microphone_rationale,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                } else {
                    // Explain in Snackbar to turn on permission in settings
                    Snackbar.make(preview, R.string.permission_microphone_explain,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                }
            }
            if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
                String[] params = permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, params, REQUEST_CAMERA_MICROPHONE);
            } else {
                // We already have permission, so handle as normal
                streamerService.startStreaming(rtmpUrl);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA_MICROPHONE: {
                Log.i(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "Received response for camera with mic permissions request.");

                // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
                // checked.
                if (Utils.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {
                    // permissions were granted, yay! do the
                    // streamer task you need to do.
                    streamerService.startStreaming(rtmpUrl);
                } else {
                    Log.i(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "Camera with mic permissions were NOT granted.");
                    Snackbar.make(preview, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            }

            // other 'switch' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
        return;
    }


    private void stopStreaming() {
        Log.d(MainActivity.APP_NAME, "stopStreaming");

        if (wakeLock != null) {
            wakeLock.release();
            wakeLock = null;
        }

        if (streamerService.isStreaming()) {
            streamerService.stopStreaming();
        }
    }

    public void endEvent(View view) {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(YouTubeApi.BROADCAST_ID_KEY, broadcastId);
        if (getParent() == null) {
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        } else {
            getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        }
        finish();
    }

}
```

Update ERROR CODE:

```
08:57:14.447  18829-18829/com.google.android.apps.watchme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.apps.watchme, PID: 18829
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ffmpeg from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.watchme-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.watchme-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.Ffmpeg.<clinit>(Ffmpeg.java:26)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.VideoStreamingConnection.open(VideoStreamingConnection.java:71)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerService.startStreaming(StreamerService.java:80)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.startStreaming(StreamerActivity.java:212)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity.access$200(StreamerActivity.java:47)
            at com.google.android.apps.watchme.StreamerActivity$1.onServiceConnected(StreamerActivity.java:64)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1110)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1127)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.any one please suggest the solution

Comment: Seems like the code references a library which does not exist in your build/ class path. Maybe you need to include this library by yourself. See https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java. Maybe this helps.

Comment: where i can add this github files.can you please give example?

Answer (score 1):

In your activity code where the calls happen, wrap it with a check:

```
int hasCamPermission = checkSelfPermission(cameraPermission);
int hasMicPermission = checkSelfPermission(microphonePermission);
```

At first add the following method to the StreamerActivity:

```
private boolean shouldCheckForPermission() {
  return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}
```

Change these lines to:

```
int hasCamPermission = shouldCheckForPermission() ? checkSelfPermission(cameraPermission) : PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
int hasMicPermission = shouldCheckForPermission() ? checkSelfPermission(microphonePermission) : PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

For this you need to compile and target with SDK 23, as stated above in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It's solved my issue.
I successfully added your code to my streameractivity file but i am getting another error?. I am updating the error code in my above section. Can you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

This method is only available for API version >= 23, with

```
targetSdkVersion 23
compileSdkVersion 23
```

And in your code you need to check the current API version before calling this method.

```
    public static boolean shouldCheckForPermission() {
      return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }
```

If this method returns true, you can call the method "checkSelfPermission".

Comment: In my android phone i am using 4.4.4 version. The sdk 23 version is enough for this android kitkat version?

Comment: Your version is API level 19. This means, you cannot call "checkSelfPermission" on this device, because it does not exist. Do the check for API level first.

Comment: I am new to android development. I don't know more about this technical side.Is that my code problem or device problem?. Please explain.

Comment: Both. Only if your devices has minimum OS Marshmallow, you can call this method in your code. If your app targets SDK level 22 then you don't need to care about "checkSelfPermission". You grant permission on install instead.

Comment: I updated my Androidmanifest.xml and StreamActivity.java file. What i need to update here .Please give some example code..